# new to SQL. unable to create table and insert values

Tags: mysql, sql

As the title states I'm unable to get seemingly valid SQL code to create table and insert values. I keep getting syntax errors from the MySQL workbench about the CREATE TABLE STATEMENT, but I'm not sure if there is actually any syntax errors. Is there anything outside of the syntax that I'm missing from my file?

```
    CREATE TABLE EMP_1 
(
    emp_num CHAR(3),
    emp_lname VARCHAR(15) not null,
    emp_fname VARCHAR(15) not null,
    emp_initial CHAR(1),
    emp_hiredate DATE,
    job_code char(3),
);

INSERT INTO EMP_1 (emp_lname, emp_fname, emp_initial, 
                   emp_hiredate, job_code) 
VALUES
    (101,"News","John","G","08-Nov-00",502),
    (102,"Senior","David","H","12-Jul-89",501),
    (103,"Arbough","June","E","01-Dec-96",500),
    (104,"Ramoras","Anne","K","15-Nov-87",501),
    (105,"Johnson","Alice","K","01-Feb-93",502),
    (106,"Smithfield","William","","22-Jun-04",500),
    (107,"Alonzo","Maria","D","10-Oct-93",500),
    (108,"Washington","Ralph","B","22-Aug-91",501),
    (109,"Smith","Larry","W","18-Jul-97",501);
```

Comment: You have an extra comma in the create table statement.

Comment: You are also trying to insert more values than specified (6 values,5 specified) and the date format is invalid (research str_to_date)

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues.

1. You have an extra comma after the last column definition.  The `create table` fails.
2. You are using double quotes instead of single quotes.  This is not a fatal error, just a bad practice because the SQL standard is single quotes.
3. Your dates should be in canonical format, YYYY-MM-DD, instead of the strings you have.  That is `'2000-11-08'` instead of `'08-Nov-00'`.
4. You specify six columns for the insert, but are only providing values for five of them.
5. You have other type problems, confusing strings and numbers.  These will be fixed with implicit conversion, but that is generally a bad idea.

Here is what the code should look like:

```
INSERT INTO EMP_1 (emp_num, emp_lname, emp_fname, emp_initial, 
                   emp_hiredate, job_code) 
    VALUES ('101', 'News', 'John', 'G', '2000-11-08', '502');
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dc28ab36368ab71dabf6c86d5b495693) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The number of fields is lesser than the values you are passing.

```
> CREATE TABLE EMP_1  (
>     emp_num CHAR(3),
>     emp_lname VARCHAR(15) not null,
>     emp_fname VARCHAR(15) not null,
>     emp_initial CHAR(1),
>     emp_hiredate DATE,
>     job_code char(3), );
> 
> INSERT INTO EMP_1 (emp_num, emp_lname, emp_fname, emp_initial,
> emp_hiredate, job_code)  VALUES
>     (101,"News","John","G","08-Nov-00",502),
>     (102,"Senior","David","H","12-Jul-89",501),
>     (103,"Arbough","June","E","01-Dec-96",500),
>     (104,"Ramoras","Anne","K","15-Nov-87",501),
>     (105,"Johnson","Alice","K","01-Feb-93",502),
>     (106,"Smithfield","William","","22-Jun-04",500),
>     (107,"Alonzo","Maria","D","10-Oct-93",500),
>     (108,"Washington","Ralph","B","22-Aug-91",501),
>     (109,"Smith","Larry","W","18-Jul-97",501);
```